# GARMA models for counts

Tags: time-series

Suppose we have count data. It seems that a generalized ARMA model would be good to use. In Rm these is function:

> garma(link = c("identity", "loge", "reciprocal",
>                  "logit", "probit", "cloglog", "cauchit"),
>         earg=list(),
>         p.ar.lag = 1, q.lag.ma = 0,
>         coefstart = NULL, step = 1)

Why type of link function would be good to use? There is no poisson option.

Answer (score 2):

There are integer valued AR processes that have been developed with some theory behind them.  My colleague Jan Sun just did her PhD dissertation on this topic at the University of Liverpool Economics Department.  Her thesis might be one good place to find references.  There was a conference on this topic in Cyrus last year.

Here is a presentation by Richard Davis from 2001:
http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~rdavis/lectures/montreal.pdf

Some more articles:

http://polisci.osu.edu/faculty/jbox/Courses/ps8125/brandtslides.pdf

https://dspace.lboro.ac.uk/dspace-jspui/handle/2134/5308

http://monogan.myweb.uga.edu/teaching/ts/mediaCount_v7.pdf

http://ideas.repec.org/p/zbw/cauewp/3194.html

http://personal.fmipa.itb.ac.id/khreshna/files/2011/02/brannas1995.pdf

http://www.statistik.tu-dortmund.de/fileadmin/user_upload/Graduiertenkolleg/AbstracsVortraege/FokianosAbstract.pdf

http://wires.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WiresArticle/wisId-WICS47.html

http://sankhya.isical.ac.in/search/71b2/paper_7.pdf

A reference on the conferene that I mentioned:
http://www2.ucy.ac.cy/~wints2011/

The first conference that came before the one above

https://sites.google.com/site/wints09/