# Distributions other than $N(0, 1)$ for the probit-style regression link function

Tags: regression, probability, logistic, probit, cauchy-distribution

When we do a probit regression, we use the distribution of a standard normal to convert from the linear combination of the predictors to a probability value.

Why stop at the standard normal? Why not other normal distributions? Why not a Cauchy distribution? Looking at the CDFs, it seems like a Cauchy-based link function would have a much higher threshold for getting close to a certain outcome with probability near $0$ or $1$. Would this be reasonable to use in a low signal-to-noise setting where we would want to be "darn sure" before we made an assertion that something was $99\%$ likely to happen?

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason to stop at the normal! What you propose, is called the *Cauchit link function*, for an example at this site, see [GARMA models for counts](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32922/garma-models-for-counts).

[Here, at arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.07748) is a paper looking at and comparing various link functions, cauchit included, for binary regression.